# Proper phototransistor for detection of small object

Tags: infrared, photoresistor

I am attempting to detect a falling objects 6mm in diameter, falling every 160ms.  The object to be detected will be confinined to a black tube, void of light, 18mm wide x 35mm long, my plan is to mount a IR led on one of the 18mm wide faces and place a detector on the opposing face. My question is what is the most suitable sensors to pick up the IR signal.

I have tried using what I believe to be photodiodes, with minimal success.  If the object falls directly in the line of sight I can see a difference in voltage on my Arduino.  I'm not sure if the response of the diode is too slow or the window of detection is too small.

I have considered photocell, but understand that they are too slow.

I believe that a photoresistor is what i should be using, but am unsure if I can have a large enough "window" to detect the falling object if it doesn't fall directly in the line of sight of the emitter and receiver.

Is a photoresistor the best choice for my application?

I am very new to electronics and have no formal training.

Comment: If your objects are falling at 160m/s, then the pulse will be very short.  The analog to digital converter (and the driving software) in an Arduino aren't fast enough for what you want to do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you just need to know when an object passed by, or do you need to know something else (like, how long it took to pass the detector?)

Comment: Photoresistor's valance band is spread out so not a good choice. Photo diode should be plenty fast.  I hesitate to post an Answer as I don't know how are you detecting the pulse from the photo diode.  Post your schematic.

Comment: "Is a photoresistor the best choice for my application?" No, it's too slow.. You want what is called a photo-interrupter. Playing with electronics is super fun and can teach you a lot, so I will strongly encurrage it, however it also takes a lot (and I mean a LOT) of studying /reading/learning and debugging something you made which doesn't work before you get it right. I would recommend that you start by practicing using excisting projects from the web as a starting point and to follow simple examples until you are more well versed.

Comment: I just want to know that an object has past.  This is a seed monitor, that will verify that seeds are dropping, thus being planted. I have build a working circuit and have done alot of testing with different configurations.  I have learn to write code for the arduino and have invested alot of time into learning.  I will continue to test and learn.  I really appreciate people who have taken time to help me here.  Thank you.  I will look into photointeruptors next.

Comment: 160 m/s is 525 feet per second - in my country (Canada), that's fast enough to reclassify a pellet gun from a toy to a regulated firearm. Are you sure the seeds are moving that fast?

Comment: I will verify, but I meant, millisecond, not meter per second.  My math, which needs verification, shows that there will be 6 seeds that would pass the sensor in 1 second.

Comment: @JRE OP is saying that objects are entering the tube every 160ms (i.e. at a frequency of 6.25Hz), not that it is travelling at 160m/s.

Comment: @DKNguyen:  When I posted that comment, the question said "160 m/s."  That's "meters per second."  It was just in the last few minutes changed to "ms" for "milliseconds."

Comment: @JRE Neuron and muscle memory cross talk.

Comment: I have two different directions to suggest. One is that you place the seeds on a rotating disc with a constraining arm that first guides the seeds along a radial trajectory and then allows them to move along a tangential vector -- this allows them to separate widely from each other. Then use a simple optical system to detect them. They can then fall, if you want. But I'd first count them when laying horizontally on a rotating disk. The other idea is if you are forced into the tube, to use multiple pixels and a fourier plane. But that's too much to write as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

given only 1/3 of the light will be blocked, you need a linear light detector.

Notice "linear".

You'll need to operate the photodetector into moderate-size resistor, or into a TIA.

The light intensity should be adjustable, so you can learn about what provides "linear" behavior.

Borrow a scope, and watch the voltage across the resistor as you drop the seeds. If you don't see about 30% drop in amplitude, you are overloading the detector with photons.